# Precision of rounded decimals giving nans for linear equation solving

Tags: python, numpy, precision

Apologies for the butchered title, not sure what I should call this.

I'm solving for the upper limit of integration of a linear equation, like in this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3878448/solving-for-limit-of-integration-of-a-linear-equation

Except the question above asks for the lower limit, and below I solve for the upper limit as `xincrements`:

```
import numpy as np

yvals = np.random.uniform(size=2)
xvals = np.random.uniform(size=2)

slope = np.diff(yvals) / np.diff(xvals)
intercept = yvals[:-1] - (xvals[:-1] * slope)

area = np.trapz(yvals, xvals)

nsplits = 100000
a = np.linspace(0, area, nsplits+1)
m = slope
b = intercept
c = xvals[0]

xincrements = ((-1*b) + np.sqrt((b**2) - (4*(0.5*m)*(-0.5*m*(c**2) - (b*c) - a)))) / m
```

This works perfectly when using random floats, and most values, as it should.

However, problems arise when introducing truncated/rounded decimals into the mix. For example using these starting points

```
xvals = np.array([317.16760254, 317.16763306])
yvals = np.array([1570203.5 ,       0.  ])
```

throws a `RunTimeWarning` because the value inside the square root function is negative. This occurs at any value of `nsplits` on the last value of `xincrements` if you start at a low `nsplits`, like 10, or 100. If you increase `nsplits` to 100000 or so, you can see this problem spreads out to more than just the last value.

It's having issues solving for values that are very close to `xvals[1]` of my specific example. I seem to run into the same problem with other truncated decimals as well.

Why is this, and is there anything I can do about this?

Comment: Can't you just add `eps=1e-10` to the values?

Comment: @NathanFurnal my googling led me to np.finfo(float).eps, but I don't understand the functionality. Is this a value of numpy I can set manually that will alter any later forming arrays? I tried it setting it down to 1e-5, and 1e-2 but I don't seen any difference in the number of `nan`s being generated.

Comment: `np.finfo` will help you add the tiniest amount possible to avoid reaching zero, it's especially useful to avoid log(0) or 1/0. If, in your case you have somewhat bigger values (like -0.1) in the square root, it'ill not fix this. 

Can you take the absolute value maybe?

Comment: I'm not sure how that would help. I'm looking for a way to still be able to solve for these values, even at a loss of precision.

Comment: it's likely a problem with floats but I'm not sure how to solve this easily, can't you just add random values < 1 to a starting point?

Comment: That's an interesting idea! I tried it out and it did work. I might use this if nothing better comes up. I was able to add a random amount between 0.001 and 0.01 with success, going lower didn't prove to be different so this might need some refinement but it's a decent starting point.

Comment: Alright, glad it's at least going somewhere!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what I ended up doing was I encased the function in a `while` loop with an enclosed `try/except` block that catches the `RuntimeWarning` given when a `nan` is produced.

I recorded the precision of `xvals` prior,

```
precision = max([str(i)[::-1].find('.') for i in xvals])
```

and decreased it by 1 via rounding every time the exception was caught.

Works rather robustly, only saw the precision go down to 0 once in ~30,000 samples.